# Windows 10 Mobile Direct3D

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile, direct3d11on12

I have a C++ project targeted for Windows Phone 8.1 that uses Direct3D11,

I tried using that project with Windows 10 Mobile device but at fails in the following line:

```
hr = D3D11CreateDevice(NULL, 
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,NULL, 
D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, 
featureLevels, 
sizeof(featureLevels) / sizeof(*featureLevels), 
D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
&m_d3dDevice, 
&featureLevel, 
NULL);
```

returning error code 0x887A002D -> DXGI_ERROR_SDK_COMPONENT_MISSING,

Any idea how i can make this work on a Windows 10 Mobile device (Preferably without migrating the project to a universal application project)?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution,

This is caused because graphics tools feature is not enabled on the device,

To enable the feature on the mobile device:

1) Open Visual Studio 2015

2) Click Debug -> Graphics -> Start Diagnostics

3) On the mobile device go to Settings -> Updates and install the update