# How do I check if the current OS is Windows 10 and the device is phone?

Tags: windows-10

In the C++ code (C# solution is OK: I can translate it to pure C++ or C++/CX) I need to check whether the code is working under Windows Phone 10 or not.

Comment: why do you need this? This sound like a XY problem. Let use try to fix your original issue that you try to solve by detecting phone/PC

Comment: Do you want check the api is working under Windows Phone 10?

Comment: I need this because Windows Phone 10 fails to create DirectX11 device with debugging layer. So if the code is running on Windows Phone 10 I want to remove that option from DX device creation flags.

Comment: call the Dx Create with debug layer, handle the return value and if the call fails, run the call without debug layer again

Comment: Yes, I know that solution.

Comment: why don't you use this approach? This is much better compared to rely on assumes which editions/SKU support which functions

Answer (score 1):

Rely on assumes which editions/SKU support which functions is a terrible bad design.

Call the `D3D11CreateDevice` call with `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` in Flags and if it returns `DXGI_ERROR_SDK_COMPONENT_MISSING` the debug layer is not avaible and call it again without this debug flag so that it works on Phone/Mobile, too.

Searching for `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` here on stackoverflow [shows this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37510950/1466046) on steps how to install the required data on mobile.